# Trigger.io Notifications: forge.notification.showLoading() not working on Android

Tags: android, notifications, trigger.io

According to the [documentation](https://trigger.io/modules/notification/current/docs/index.html#forgenotificationshowloadingtitle-body-success-error), `forge.notification.showLoading()` should work on both Android and iOS. I'm using:

```
forge.notification.showLoading('Getting GPS location.');
```

right before a `forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`, how ever it doesn't display anything on Android. On iOS I get the expected result. Am I missing something?

I'm testing on two different 4.4.2 (physical) devices, no notification. The code seems to be working, after a bit I do get the Position, and the code continues (closing the loading spinner on iOS) doing some more stuff. For iOS I'm using the Simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem was that I wasn't using the right params:

```
forge.notification.showLoading('title', 'body');
```

iOS only needs the `title`, but Android does show both `title` and `body`. Hope it helps somebody.